# lightbox, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, popup

I would like to add 6-7 transparent popups on a html page, I added 4 until now 1 and 2 are working fine, 3 and 4 do popup when I press the link but after that if I wanna close them the transparent background disappear but the middle window remain... I will attach the html code and the css (its a very simple code and even so I cant figure out whats wrong)

I appreciate all the HELP thank you all!

Thank you very much for the answer how to add the code :)

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

/* This is a style of dim effect onClick on Register or Log in button - it's the transparent background*/
.black_overlay1, .black_overlay2, .black_overlay3, .black_overlay4{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}


/* This is a style for log in and registration form */
.white_box  {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 25%;
   left: 25%;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   padding: 16px;
   border: 5px solid #ffffff;
   background-color: #cee9ad;
   z-index:1002;
   overflow: auto;
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Simple lightBox effect with css and javascript
        </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
<!-- BUTTONS for LogIn and Register -->

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Energy Efficient</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Cost efficient</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light3').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Sustainability &amp; Safety</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light4').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Time Saving</a>


<!-- LOG IN FORM - WRITE DOWN HERE -->
        <div id="light1" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Energy Efficient</p>
        </div>

        <div id="light2" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Cost efficient</p>
        </div>

        <div id="light3" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Sustainability &amp; Safety</p>
        </div>

        <div id="light4" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Time Saving</p>
        </div>




<!-- Javascript for hidding div with LogIn form and the fade effect with it -->

        <a onclick="document.getElementById('light2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade" class="black_overlay1" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a onclick="document.getElementById('light2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade" class="black_overlay2" onclick = "document.getElementById('light2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a onclick="document.getElementById('light2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade" class="black_overlay3" onclick = "document.getElementById('light3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a onclick="document.getElementById('light2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade" class="black_overlay4" onclick = "document.getElementById('light4').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
            </div>
        </a>


<!-- Other content on the page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cut & paste into the editor, highlight the code, and hit `ctrl-k`, or hit the `{}` button.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error are caused by duplicate `ID` attribute values including the ones passed to `getElementById` functions.

Here's the fixed HTML code. I've converted the scripts in `ONCLICK` attributes to two functions in a `SCRIPT` block to make them more manageable and easier to read.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Simple lightBox effect with css and javascript
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

        <script>
        function doshow(num) {
            document.getElementById('light'+num).style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('fade'+num).style.display='block';
        }
        function dohide(num) {
            document.getElementById('light'+num).style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('fade'+num).style.display='none';
        }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
<!-- BUTTONS for LogIn and Register -->

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "doshow(1)">Energy Efficient</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "doshow(2)">Cost efficient</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "doshow(3)">Sustainability &amp; Safety</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "doshow(4)">Time Saving</a>


<!-- LOG IN FORM - WRITE DOWN HERE -->
        <div id="light1" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Energy Efficient</p>
        </div>

        <div id="light2" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Cost efficient</p>
        </div>

        <div id="light3" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Sustainability &amp; Safety</p>
        </div>

        <div id="light4" class="white_box" style="position: absolute; left: 607px; top: 120px; width:630px; height:560px">      
            <p>Time Saving</p>
        </div>


<!-- Javascript for hidding div with LogIn form and the fade effect with it -->

        <a onclick="dohide(1)" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade1" class="black_overlay1">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a onclick="dohide(2)" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade2" class="black_overlay2">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a onclick="dohide(3)" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade3" class="black_overlay3">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a onclick="dohide(4)" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="fade4" class="black_overlay4">
            </div>
        </a>


<!-- Other content on the page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the answer and help <3, could you please help me how can I add a close button X in one of the corners? I tried some codes from the net but no luck to make them work, thank you